# android TabHost invoking another Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost

I have a `MainActivity.java` in which there are `TabHost` declared as follows:

```
Intent intent_comment   = new Intent(this,Comments.class);
createTab("Comments",intent_comment);

private void createTab(String text ,Intent intent)
{               tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(text).setIndicator(createTabView(text)).setContent(intent));
}
```

and then inside this `Comments.class`, there are just 4 buttons in the page, of which once the buttons are pressed, i would like to show the `Comment_movie.class`: a `scrollview` (just like a webpage) with buttons inside, such that when buttons are pressed, it would invoke other activities.

Therefore, what I have done is simply inside the `Comments.class`

```
public void button_story_movie_click (View view) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent (Comments.this, Comment_movie.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    Comments.this.finish();    
}
```

But then it goes error,

### logcat as follows:

```
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.abc/com.abc.abc.Comment_movie}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.abc.abc.Comment_movie cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.abc.abc.Comment_movie cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2025)
06-09 13:02:27.185: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    ... 11 more
```

### Questions / intention:

How could I invoke another activity inside `TabHost`?? 
And is it possible to show the targeted activity by replacing the original `Comments` layout (is it so called fragment?) still showing the Tabs at the top of the screen?

Many thanks!! I am new to use TabHost but got stuck. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: please inser your complete error logcat.thanks

Comment: @MM-BB thanks for your prompt reply! I have added full logcat

Comment: @ pearmak are you sure that not exist after (... 11 more) logcat error ?thankyou

Comment: @MM-BB that ...11 more cannot be expanded anymore... thanks~

Comment: By `invoke another activity inside TabHost`, so you mean that you want to replace the fragment ? An activity will cover the whole screen by default and will hide your tabs. I think you are talking about fragments. Is it?

Comment: @ Shobhit Puri: thanks!! i really want to still showing the tabs actually, but i dont know how to make that, and hence now invoking an actually completely full-screened and hide up all the tabs...how to make that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment_movie should extend activity:

```
public class Comment_movie extends Activity {

    // ...class content
}
```

Comment: thanks and sorry for this simple careless mistake. also i have researched and found out it can be made using `ActivityGroup` in order to maintain showing the Tabs, but most research says it is better to use `ViewPager` which can also add sliding animation.